# create a zip but cannot extract

Tags: php, zip

I managed to zip the files and downloaded it. The only problem is that I cant extract the zip file is says "An error occured while loading the archive". It contains data since it has around 1000kb. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip_name = "zipfile.zip";

if($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    echo("Zip failed");
} else {
  foreach($temp_file as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file, $file);
  }   

 $zip->close();

 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=media.zip');
 header('Content-type: application/zip');
 readfile($zip_name);
}
```

Comment: are you tried with manual or through code?

Comment: I manually extract it.

Comment: What are you extracting it with?

Comment: try with through code

Comment: I'm using ubuntu's archive manager to extract.

Answer (score 0):

- I've added a variable `$zipname` to contain the full path to your "zipfile.zip". It is later used to determine the filesize, which is send with the content-length header. Please adjust the path!
- added some more headers, especially length and pragma
- adjusted length and disposition to use dynamic filenames based on the variables on the top
- added exit() after readfile() - rare, but you never know the registered shutdown handlers and their output behaviour
- keep in mind, if you have large files you are sending through readfile() and you have a busy site, this will consume memory

Give it a try:

```
 <? 

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    $zip_name = "/path/to/zipfile.zip"; // <-- adjust path
    $file_name = basename($zip_name);

    if($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        echo("Zip failed");
    } else {

        foreach($temp_file as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file, $file);
        }   

        $zip->close();

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_name));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($zip_name);

        exit;
    }
```